# Android SQLite data displaying

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm kinda new in android development and I am little confused about `content providers`. `Content providers` are used to share your data with other application legally, but is it correct to use it for retrieving your data from `SQLite database`and display it in, for instance `listView`? What is better solution for displaying data from db?
Thanks

Comment: yes, it is correct to use it for list view, although it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is legit using the ContentProvider to retrieve data from a SQLite database while its perfectly fine creating an Handler to handle the SQLiteOpenHelper and just using it.

Its all depends on your app's needs,
Me individually for my own app if no need for sharing data wouldn't use a content provider.

Comment: And what would you use to retrieve data fom db and display it?

Comment: I would create a class which gets me the data and brings it to the ui if its a big data list i would use a recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to share the data base from your app it's not necessary to use a Content Provider